# How to draw a rectangle in a JButton Action Listener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, paintcomponent

I'm trying to do something where the user gets a prompt where they can pick a colour from the JColorChooser and once they've done that, a rectangle pops up in the same JFrame and it has the same colour as what the user picked

Code so far:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestProjectDialog {

    static String name;


    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    TestProjectJPanel jpp = new TestProjectJPanel();

    public static void main(String[] args){




    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Just about to draw a REALLY GOOD 2D car \n just need input please.");

     name= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Imagine a car, what is it's name?");
    if(name == null || (name != null && ("".equals(name))))   
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input/pressed cancel, closing program.");
      System.exit(0);
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ah okay, so it's name is " + name); 

    JFrame f = new JFrame(name);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    TestProjectJPanel jpp = new TestProjectJPanel();


    jpp.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    f.setSize(1440,900);
    f.add(jpp.panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.add(jpp.b, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    f.setVisible(true);



    }


}
```

And for the class which has the button, listener and where I want the Rectangle to appear

```
    import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;


public class TestProjectJPanel extends JFrame {



    public JButton b;
    public Color color = (Color.WHITE);
    public JPanel panel;
    public Color bodyColour;
    public Color doorColour;
    public Color wheelColour;




        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ // Surely this shouldn't be void as it's returning a Rectangle?
            super.paintComponents(g);
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(430,50,250,400);
            g.fillRect((int)r.getX(),(int)r.getY(),(int)r.getHeight(),(int)r.getWidth());
            g.setColor(bodyColour);
        }


    public TestProjectJPanel(){
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(color);

        // bodyColour button
        b = new JButton("Choose a colour for the body of the car");
        b.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                        bodyColour = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Pick the colour", bodyColour);
                        if(bodyColour==null) 
                            bodyColour = (Color.BLACK);

                        // TRYING TO DRAW THE RECTANGLE HERE ONCE THE USER PICKED THEIR COLOUR.

                    }
                }
                );

    }

        }
```

Comment: In the future, please post more than just requirements and a code dump. Please try to ask a specific and answerable question. 1+ to MadProgrammer for trying to answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).

As a hint, don't override `paint` of top level containers like `JFrame`, create a custom `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method and perform your custom painting there (don't forget to call `super.paintComponent`).

Provide methods to that allow you to change the color of the rectangle and call `repaint` to request that the panel should be updated.

Comment: Just edited, I meant to put paintComponent, and then super.paintComponents(g); as unfortanetly, I get an error when I try to do super.paintComponent(g);

Comment: `JFrame` doesn't have a `paintComponent` method

Comment: @SebastianA: always use the `@Override` annotation when you're trying to create an override method. If you did that, you'd know immediately what Mad posted above was true.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time! But I think I understand now. Thankyou